# Visual Basic 2010 - Retrieving numbers from an html div

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, html, html-parsing

I'm currently working on a program that will average the prices from a searched item on `Amazon`.

I have button on the program that when pressed, prints out the `HTML` source code into a `richtextbox` and then finds the specific `div` within the source code.

My only problem right now is having it print out the money amount after each `div`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)**, one of the best HTML parsing libraries to ease this task.
An **[example](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)**.

**Examples:**

*Assuming div's id is divPrice*

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(yourHTML);
        HtmlNode priceNode = doc.GetElementbyId("divPrice");
        string price = priceNode.InnerText;
```

Let's say div has no id but a css class *cssPrice*, then you can query it with XPath:

```
        HtmlNode priceNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='cssPrice']");
```

**OR**

```
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='cssPrice']");
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes) {
            string nodeText = node.InnerText;
        }
```